# How to fix 'Double data loading' from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database for a small project.We have a list of students from single department.The purpose is to lend money to some other student and we keep the record.

I have user authenticated user firebase Authentication.The issue i am facing is once a user adds more entries , instead of loading the actual list , it creates copies.
[image]

Here is my code to load data in recycler view.
    private void loadtorecyclerview() {

```
    databaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Transaction");


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                readTransaction = snapshot.getValue(Transaction.class);
                if (readTransaction.getSponsor_id().contentEquals(user.getUserId().toString())) {
                  read_data.add(readTransaction);
                  Log.e("log" , readTransaction.toString());
                }
            }

               transactionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

I am calling this method in OnCreateView of my fragment.

Here is code to add new data to firebase.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String amount = editText.getText().toString();

                setValue(amount);

                //value published firebase
                Log.e("amount" , amount);
                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Transaction");
                String key = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                databaseReference.child(key).setValue(transaction_submitted);


            //    loadtorecyclerview();


                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Here is code for Transaction Adapter.

```
public class TransactionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransactionAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Transaction> data;

    public TransactionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Transaction> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = (View) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_item_sponsor_rv  , parent ,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.amount.setText(data.get(position).getAmount());
        holder.department.setText(data.get(position).getDepartment());
        holder.collector.setText(data.get(position).getCollector_name());
        holder.published.setText(data.get(position).getPublished_at());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return data.size();

    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView published;
        TextView department;
        TextView amount;
        TextView collector;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            published = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            department = itemView.findViewById(R.id.department);
            amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            collector = itemView.findViewById(R.id.collector);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see in image there are three entries in Transaction , but when loaded , it duplicates them and show many.

Comment: Seems a problem with the adapter. Please attach the code of the `TransactionAdapter` class.

Comment: @salmanwahed please check the updated code.

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: @salmanwahed i used this:

                read_data.clear();
transaction_adapter.notifydatasetchanged() and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with the adapter setting. You are adding values to the data-set without removing the old ones. Please reinitialize/clear the `read_data` object before adding new items to it.

```
databaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Transaction");

read_data.clear();

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                readTransaction = snapshot.getValue(Transaction.class);
                if (readTransaction.getSponsor_id().contentEquals(user.getUserId().toString())) {
                  read_data.add(readTransaction);
                  Log.e("log" , readTransaction.toString());
                }
            }

               transactionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```